# LDAP Migration to new LDAP Server

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap

I need to move my ldap server to a newer one. It is currently running on Ubuntu 7.04 server.
Is there a way of backing up this server, installing a fresh openldap server on a newer Ubuntu 11.04 server, and restoring the old database to it?

I've tried backing up to a LDIF and restoring it to a new openldap server but I guess it wasn't able to restore the configuration with it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Backing up to LDIF and restoring it should be the simplest way. Quickest way to get your answer would probably be to post exactly what went wrong here.

Comment: Also make sure you have the same schema.

Comment: Did you do the LDIF dump using ldapsearch or slapcat? Make sure to use slapcat/slapadd for backup/restore.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration should be in just one file. On 7.04, I believe you had a /etc/ldap/ldap.conf, where your config is. You should be able to move the config file to a new system, and either start openldap with this config file with the -f argument, or you could you also convert to using a dynamic backend, which you probably will not want to do, because of added complexity. Since you were able to dump your contents with slapcat and can import them, the only missing bit is your config file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot migrate using replication, ubuntu 7.1 comes with openldap 2.2 which dont have syncrepl, It only have slurpd. Ubuntu 11 comes with openldap 2.4 which have syncrepl not slurpd. It is possible to migrate online from Openldap 2.2 to Openldap 2.3 & openldap 2.3 to Openldap 2.4, but definitely not Openldap 2.2 to Openldap 2.4.

You need to take backup of your ldap tree & add again.

Take the back up data on old LDAP server system using ldapsearch or slapcat

```
$ldapsearch -x -LLL -b "dc=yourbase,dc=com" -D "cn=Manager,dc=yourbase,dc=com"  -W  >> mybackup.ldif
```

or use slapcat, but make sure slapd is stopped before running slapcat.

```
$slapcat -l /tmp/backup.ldif
```

After exporting it to a file,Remove the below attributes from the backup file. If slapcat method is used.

```
entryUUID|creatorsName|structuralObjectClass|createTimestamp|entryCSN|modifiersName|modifyTimestamp| contextCSN
```

Import the ldif file using ldapadd command

```
$slapadd -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d/ -n 0 -l /tmp/backup1.ldif
```

For cases where third party schema files are being used in ubuntu 7.1 , after copying the schema files to ubuntu11, if any schema violation occurs like OID's used in third party schema files may not be compatible with OpenLDAP versions of ubuntu 11, In which case contact the vendor who have provided the schema files.

Answer (score 0):

If you're moving from a 32bit machine to a 64bit machine, OpenLDAP's data may not be compatible. I was not able to find documentation in OpenLDAP's docs for the process of migrating data, but the Zimbra docs might be able to point you in the right direction: http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Network_Edition:_Moving_from_32-bit_to_64-bit_Server

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

Get a copy of your data on the old server by running the following command:

```
ldapsearch -z max -LLL -Wx -D "cn=admin,dc=your,dc=domain" -b "dc=your,dc=base" > save.ldif
```

Move the file to the new server and import it by running:

```
ldapmodify -c -Wx -D "cn=admin,dc=your,dc=domain" -a -f save.ldif
```